# Replace specific tag value in xml based on condition

Tags: xml, shell, vim, replace, scripting

We have to replace the password present in xml ***for specific environment***.
for example if the `<id>dev</id>`, we want to replace the oraclePassword from `<oraclePassword>dev1</oraclePassword>` to `<oraclePassword>devPassword</oraclePassword>`

```
$cat settings.xml
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <oracleServerT3>t3://soa-server1-dev:7001</oracleServerT3>
        <oracleUsername>admin</oracleUsername>
        <oraclePassword>dev1</oraclePassword>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>int</id>
      <properties>
        <oracleServerT3>t3://soa-server1-int:7001</oracleServerT3>
        <oracleUsername>admin</oracleUsername>
        <oraclePassword></oraclePassword>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>usr</id>
      <properties>
        <oracleServerT3>t3://soa-server1-usr:7001</oracleServerT3>
        <oracleUsername>admin</oracleUsername>
        <oraclePassword>usr1</oraclePassword>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

TIA

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I am not very good at linux scripting, but spent many hours and could only find option to search and replace a text either through sed or awk or pearl but our requirement is to have additional condition, which probably involves xml parsing or some other way to do that.

Below command simply does find and replace, but not quiet what we want:
awk '{sub("<oraclePassword>dev1</oraclePassword>", "<oraclePassword>mango</oraclePassword>"); print}' settings.xml

Comment: Add your command to your question and explain how it fails.

Comment: My command works to replace the first occurance of the password:

awk '{sub("<oraclePassword>dev1</oraclePassword>", "<oraclePassword>mango</oraclePassword>"); print}' settings.xml 

But that doesn't cover the requirement. The requirement is to do search and replace based on condition and probably involves xml parsing, which I dont know how to do as I am from a different technology, hence asking question here.

Comment: In. The. Question.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I have found the solution, will try it for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Please(!) use an XML-parser like [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) or [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to edit your XML-file:

```sh
$ xmlstarlet ed -O \
  -u '//profile[id="dev"]/properties/oraclePassword/text()' \
  -v 'devPassword' \
  settings.xml
```

```sh
$ xidel -s settings.xml -e '
  x:replace-nodes(
    //profile[id="dev"]/properties/oraclePassword/text(),
    "devPassword"
  )
' --printed-node-format=xml
```